# postgresql condition column name = data

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables.

```
table a
 | uid | name    | number | 
 |-----+---------+--------|
 | 1   | table   | 1      |
 | 2   | chair   | 2      |

table b
 | uid | name    | number | 
 |-----+---------+--------|
 | 1   | john    | 1      |
 | 2   | billy   | 0      |
 | 3   | bob     | 2      |
 | 4   | sally   | 1      |

table c 
 | uid | table a | john    | billy  | bob  | sally | 
 |-----+---------+--------+--------+-------|-------|
 | 1   | table   |    T   |        |       |  T    |
 | 2   | chair   |        |        |   C   |       |
```

What I need to be able to do is look at the column names in table c, find the corresponding row entry in table b and if the numbers are the same as the numbers from table a, then set the table c value to T. Otherwise set it to C. This needs to be triggered whenever either table a or table b are updated.

How can I write an update the table using if or case statement.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just generate `c` when you need it rather than going through the effort of maintaining it for inserts, updates, and deletes?

Comment: Table a and table b gets automatically updated by a separate table. so I just want to call a trigger on update of any of the table.

Comment: You must have a good reason for such complication.  `c` is derived entirely from the other two tables, so storing it separately is bad database design -- unless you have a good reason for the redundancy.